# Paint node panels on gojs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gojs

Hi I want to paint my node like the right node, there is any idea how can I do it with GOjs

on the left node this is what I get when I try to paint it.
the right node is what I really want to paint.

its looks like he miss some parts.

I've try to build 2 panels on the node but because the shape is rounded I Cant paint all the panel.

[image]

```
    var simpleNode = $(
  go.Node,
  "Auto",
  new go.Binding("layerName", "category"),
  $(
    go.Panel,
    "Auto",

    $(
      go.Shape,
      "RoundedRectangle",
      {
        portId: "", // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
        fromLinkable: true,
        fromLinkableDuplicates: false,
        toLinkableDuplicates: false,
        toLinkable: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
      },
      new go.Binding("fill", "color"),


    ),
    $(
      go.Panel,
      "Horizontal",
      {
        alignment: go.Spot.Left,

        minSize: new go.Size(160, 0),
      },
      $(
        go.Panel,
        "Horizontal",
        {
          background: "#800080",
          stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill,
          margin: new go.Margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
        },
        $(
          go.Shape,

          {
            margin: new go.Margin(0, 15, 2, 15),
            fill: "white",
            strokeWidth: 0,
            background: "transparent",
            maxSize: new go.Size(20, 20),
            cursor: "pointer",
          },
          new go.Binding("geometry", geoFunc)
        )
      ),
      $(
        go.Panel,
        "Vertical",
        {
          background: "transparent",
        },
        $(
          go.TextBlock,
          {
            margin: new go.Margin(15, 15, 0, 15),
            editable: false, // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            stroke: "white",
            font: "14px Segoe UI",
          },

        ),
        $(
          go.TextBlock,
          {
            margin: new go.Margin(0, 15, 15, 15),
            editable: false, // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            stroke: "white",
            font: "12px Segoe UI",
            alignment: go.Spot.Left,
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "id")
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define two shapes that are the left and right sides of a rounded rectangle, then you can do this easily:

```js
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { strokeWidth: 0 },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal", { margin: 3 }, // Margin will control how big the border is
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedLeftRectangle", { strokeWidth: 0, fill: 'red', width: 30, height: 60 }),
          $(go.Shape, "RoundedRightRectangle", { strokeWidth: 0, fill: 'purple', width: 100, height: 60 })
         )
      );
```

The definitions for those shapes:

```
go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("RoundedLeftRectangle", function (shape, w, h) {
  // this figure takes one parameter, the size of the corner
  var p1 = 5;  // default corner size
  if (shape !== null) {
    var param1 = shape.parameter1;
    if (!isNaN(param1) && param1 >= 0) p1 = param1;  // can't be negative or NaN
  }
  p1 = Math.min(p1, w);  // limit by width & height
  p1 = Math.min(p1, h/3);
  var geo = new go.Geometry();
  // a single figure consisting of straight lines and quarter-circle arcs
  geo.add(new go.PathFigure(w, 0)
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, w, h))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, p1, h))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, 90, 90, p1, h - p1, p1, p1))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, 0, p1))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, 180, 90, p1, p1, p1, p1).close()));
  // don't intersect with two top corners when used in an "Auto" Panel
  geo.spot1 = new go.Spot(0, 0, 0.3 * p1, 0.3 * p1);
  geo.spot2 = new go.Spot(1, 1, -0.3 * p1, 0);
  return geo;
});

go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("RoundedRightRectangle", function (shape, w, h) {
  // this figure takes one parameter, the size of the corner
  var p1 = 5;  // default corner size
  if (shape !== null) {
    var param1 = shape.parameter1;
    if (!isNaN(param1) && param1 >= 0) p1 = param1;  // can't be negative or NaN
  }
  p1 = Math.min(p1, w);  // limit by width & height
  p1 = Math.min(p1, h/3);
  var geo = new go.Geometry();
  // a single figure consisting of straight lines and quarter-circle arcs
  geo.add(new go.PathFigure(0, 0)
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, w - p1, 0))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, 270, 90, w - p1, p1, p1, p1))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, w, h - p1))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, 0, 90, w - p1, h - p1, p1, p1))
    .add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, 0, h).close()));
  // don't intersect with two bottom corners when used in an "Auto" Panel
  geo.spot1 = new go.Spot(0, 0, 0.3 * p1, 0);
  geo.spot2 = new go.Spot(1, 1, -0.3 * p1, -0.3 * p1);
  return geo;
});
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/RwLZxwp

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. its pretty close from what I want, I don't want a border at all there is soultion for that?